# Put result of ajax request inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to take the result of my console log and put it in a div. The console log bit works, but not putting it in a div. According to the online tutorials it should be something like this:

```
<div id="number">Test</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'report.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.report.data[0].breakdown[0].counts);
                $('#number').innerHTML = data.report.data[0].breakdown[0].counts;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However I get no log errors, it just doesn't update the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

`$('#number').html(data.report.data[0].breakdown[0].counts)`

instead of .innerHTML

Comment: Ah that's perfect, thank you. Will accept in 12 misn.

Answer (score 0):

Since you using jQuery Selector `$`, you need to use `$('#number').html("text or something")`.
Or maybe you can do `document.querySelectorAll("#number").innerHTML = "text or somthing"` if you want to use Vanila Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#number')` is a jquery object, `.innerHTML` works on a DOM object - they are not the same thing.

Either convert `$('#number')` to DOM, with:

```
$('#number')[0].innerHTML = data.report.data[0].breakdown[0].counts;
```

Or use jquery method:

```
$('#number').html(data.report.data[0].breakdown[0].counts);
```